# Electrolysis of sodium chloride solution

Tags: water, electrolysis

I am trying to understand electrolysis. My question  is: when electrolysis is done with a NaCl solution I have learnt that sodium metal is not formed. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at these two redox couples:
$$\ce{Na+ + e- <=> Na}  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,E^0(\mathrm{red})=-2.71 V $$
$$\ce{2H2O + 2e- <=> H2 +2OH- }\,\,\,\,  E^0(\mathrm{red})=-0.83 V $$
Because it is much easier to reduce water than $\ce{Na+}$ ions, the only product formed at the cathode is hydrogen gas.

Answer (score 2):

The electrolysis of molten NaCl indeed gives elemental sodium and chlorine gas:

$\ce {2NaCl (l) -> 2Na (l) + Cl2 (g)}$

However, in solution (namely aqueous solution such that you are doing the electrolysis on a solution of NaCl in water), the highly reactive Na produced reacts instantly with water to give sodium hydroxide, hence why no solid Na is ever observed.